# How to modify a Jenkins pipeline job's property programmatically?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, groovy

We set up a Jenkins job in multiple folders that has the following "Choice Parameter" property.
[image]

How can I modify the property programmatically to add more choices? For example, I want to add a `feature` and `devops` choice. I know I can just got to each individual job and add them, but that's just not DevOpsy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to define your pipelines [as code](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#defining-a-pipeline-in-scm). That way they will always be up-to-date with the code they build, and much easier to maintain.

You will end up with a [Jenkinsfile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) in your repository that represents your pipeline along with all the parameters, steps, agent requirements, environment variables, triggers, and other elements.

There are several built-in types of parameters, with many others are available as plugins.

The `choices` parameter would look like this, with the first element of the list being the default value:

```java
parameters 
    {
        choice name: 'ENVIRONMENT', 
            choices: [
                'sandbox', 
                'staging',
                'production',
                'feature',
                'devops'
            ],
            description: 'The environment to deploy the application to'
    }
```

If you want to use a single Jenkinsfile for multiple jobs, you can either do the same but manually checkout the desired repository in the first stage, or explore the abilities provided by [shared libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). Both options have an obvious drawback - if the application code requires changes to the pipeline, you will have to make them in the pipeline repository first. And to apply them gradually (e.g. modify the apps one by one if required), you will need to maintain two or more pipeline versions simultaneously and make sure they always work correctly.

Note that unlike other CI servers, Jenkins is unable to automatically pick up the pipeline parameters changes until the start of the next build, so you may need to implement some workaround for that, i.e. adding a `stage` that aborts the build if some dummy parameter value is changed.

Comment: Thanks. I normally do it this way, but in this case someone else has created this jobs already and I just want to "modify" that part, and not "change" them with Jenkinsfiles.

Comment: Oh, I see. But there is no way to bulk edit the jobs. There is a thing called [JobDSL](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/job-dsl/), that allows to generate (and re-generate) the jobs from the source, but it also comes with a number of consequences. The most DevOpsy turn you can make then is set up and force the RBAC via JCasC and prohibit editing the jobs via UI.